Issue with Meta Phone Number Verification and Certificate Availability
In our Meta account, we have added our real number as the chatbot number, included our business details, and Meta has verified our business name. Although there is an option to send messages using a template, we still cannot send a test message. The phone number status has remained pending for more than two weeks after adding the number, and the certificate is not available for our business.
We still cannot send a test messages. Could you please assist us in resolving this issue so we can proceed with our chatbot testing and message sending?

Were you able to solve this? I'0m still blocked at the same point

We only needed to register the number using the endpoint "https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/[phone-number-id]/register" without associating any certificate and then the number was ready for use. Here is the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/registration
